# Analyzer, what replaces parameterKind

Tags: dart, analyzer

**issue:**
ParameterElement's **parameterKind** is marked as "Deprecated", no mention of what replaces it. A quick look at Analyzer yields extensive use of ParameterKind still.

Questions:

- What replaces parameterKind?
- How can I redo this:
  `arg.parameterKind == ParameterKind.REQUIRED`

Comment: Could you provide some more context about what you're talking about?

Comment: I'm working on a json generator, and that check is used to check if the constructor is required... it works now, but the flagging of parameterKind as deprecated has me worried since it lacks a comment as to what replaces it on:
/lib/dart/element/element.dart

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you modifying (or directly using) the `dartanalyzer` code itself?

Comment: Looking at the code, I will *guess* that instead of checking `arg.parameterKind` that you should be checking `arg.isOptional`, `arg.isPositional`, `arg.isNamed`, etc. directly.

Comment: Yup, thank you!, that did it!